# Unable to Unwrap WETH

Tags: solidity, wrapped-tokens

I am writing a smart contract that needs to Unwrap/Withdraw WETH at some point but the transaction is always reverting.

When calling this function, everything works perfectly fine and the Log I put in the receive function even picks up the fact that I received the ETH.

```
    WETH.withdraw(WETH.balanceOf(address(this)));
```

[image]
But I still get an error with the Withdraw function..
[image]
Does anyone have an idea of why this might be?

Thank you

Complete code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./weth.sol";
contract Unwrap {
    fallback() external payable {}
    receive() external payable {}
    function unwrap() external payable {
        IWETH weth = IWETH(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2);
        weth.withdraw(weth.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your contract have a payable fallback or receive function? Without one of those, calls to WETH.withdraw will fail since it can't send the ETH back to the contract

Comment: Hello, yes it does have it. I even put a log inside the payable receive function in order to be sure it was sent to the function and it does show up in the tx events. @natewelch_

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to *approve* the amount you are unwrapping

Comment: No it is not needed when unwrapping Ether. I still have no idea why the code is not working sadly

Comment: unwrapping is just reducing the ERC20 balance and sending it to the contract so isnt it approving it for transfer?